# How can I tell the difference between types of assimilation?

Tags: phonology, pronunciation, parts-of-speech, assimilation

I am currently studying linguistics (new to the subject) and I have a challenging time understanding the different assimilation forms.
So far we studied these:

- Assimilation of voicing only (place and manner aren't changing)
- Assimilation of place only
- Assimilation of manner only
- and Assimilation of manner AND place.
- also anticipatory of place.

My problem is I want to practice some exercises to tell the difference, and I cannot find any online examples that can help me out. I also need to know if there are any specific patterns.
Can someone be kind enough to help out?:)

Answer (score 5):

This is less of an absolute classification, and more just a description of what's happening in a particular circumstance in a particular language.

Assimilation means one thing is becoming more like another thing. That means some properties are getting changed, to become more similar.

What properties are getting changed? `[b]` is a voiced bilabial stop, `[m]` is a voiced bilabial nasal, so if `[b]` turns into `[m]` that's assimilation of manner: the manner is the property that's changing. If `[b]` turns into `[d]` on the other hand, the place is the property that's changing, and if `[b]` turns into `[p]`, the voicing is the property that's changing.

In other words, just write out the properties of the before-sound and the after-sound, and look at which ones changed. That's the type of assimilation it is.